# How to send current page number and length to server

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I followed the DataTable documentation and implemented as below,data is  reendered but pagiantion not working properly.

How can I get the actual **pageNumber**(table.page.info().page) when I clicked on page number on right bottom corner of dataTable and actula **pageSize**(table.page.info().length) when I change the page length on left top corner of datatable before ajax call.

Example 1: When I click on Page Number "1"  I get -

```
Page Number 0 Page Size 10
```

But it should be

```
Page Number 1 Page Size 10
```

Example 2 : When I change page length "10" to "25" I get -

```
Page Number 0 Page Size 10
```

But it should be

```
Page Number 0 Page Size 25
```

That means I am one step behind,Please help....

**Here is my html**

```
<table id="allScholarshipResult" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Scholarship Year</th>
            <th>Scholarship Level</th>
            <th>Total Candidate</th>
            <th>Boy</th>
            <th>Girl</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Scholarship Year</th>
            <th>Scholarship Level</th>
            <th>Total Candidate</th>
            <th>Boy</th>
            <th>Girl</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**Here is the js**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var url = 'all';
   var pageNumber;
   var pageSize;
   var table =  $('#allScholarshipResult').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "paging": true,
          "searching": { "regex": true },
          ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {

               $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                         pageNumber: pageNumber,
                         pageSize: pageSize
                    },
                    success: function( response, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                         pageNumber = table.page.info().page;
                         pageSize= table.page.info().length;
                         console.log('Page Number '+pageNumber + ' Page Size ' + pageSize);
                         callback({
                              data: response.responseObject.data,
                              recordsTotal:  response.responseObject.recordsTotal,
                              recordsFiltered:  response.responseObject.recordsFiltered
                         });
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    }
               });
          },
          columns: [
               { data: "id" },
               { data: "examYear" },
               { data: "scholarshipLevelId" },
               { data: "candidateTotal" },
               { data: "candidateBoy" },
               { data: "candidateGirl" },
            ]

     });
    } );
```

**Response returned from API**

```
{
  "recordsTotal": 5,
  "recordsFiltered": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 76,
      "examYear": 2020,
      "scholarshipLevelId": 1,
      "candidateTotal": 0,
      "candidateBoy": 0,
      "candidateGirl": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 75,
      "examYear": 2020,
      "scholarshipLevelId": 1,
      "candidateTotal": 0,
      "candidateBoy": 0,
      "candidateGirl": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 74,
      "examYear": 2019,
      "scholarshipLevelId": 2,
      "candidateTotal": 0,
      "candidateBoy": 0,
      "candidateGirl": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 73,
      "examYear": 2019,
      "scholarshipLevelId": 1,
      "candidateTotal": 0,
      "candidateBoy": 0,
      "candidateGirl": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 72,
      "examYear": 2020,
      "scholarshipLevelId": 2,
      "candidateTotal": 0,
      "candidateBoy": 0,
      "candidateGirl": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first time, the value of `pageNumber` and `pageSize` that you will get in the server will be **undefined**. Once you get the response from the server, then you are setting the value of `pageNumber` and `pageSize` to the table's page number and page length which is at the current point of time will be **0** and **10** respectively.

Now, whenever you hit any page, let's say **5** for that matter, you will be getting **0** in the server instead of **4**.

I'll sugget you to make use of `settings` object that is being passed in the ajax function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'all';
    var table = $('#allScholarshipResult').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "paging": true,
      "searching": { "regex": true },
      ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings); // <--- create new api object using settings object
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                      pageNumber: api.page(), // <---- get page number
                      pageSize: api.page.len(), //<--- get page length
                },
            });
      },
  });
});
```